# Facebook Login Button Throws An Error And Says I Cannot Login

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook, swift

I have created a button which lets my user log in via Facebook in conjunction with Parse.

I am using iOS 9.1 beta and Xcode 7 beta 3.
Currently this is my swift code for my IBAction. The Facebook button somewhat works but doesn't actually let me login leaving me with the error shown in the picture below. Unsure as to why this is as my pList is all up to date with Facebook iOS9 procedures.

View Controller Code:

```
 }

@IBAction func fbLoginClick(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if user == nil {

            NSLog("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")

        } else if user!.isNew {

            NSLog("User signed up and logged in through Facebook! \(user)")

        } else {

            NSLog("User logged in through Facebook! \(user)")

        }

    }
}
}
```

App Delegate Code:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    Parse.setApplicationId("Parse ID",
        clientKey: "Client Key")

    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptionsInBackground(launchOptions, block: nil)
    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) { 

}

 func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {

}

func application(application: UIApplication,
openURL url: NSURL,
sourceApplication: String?,
annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
        openURL: url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)
```

}

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 0):

check App setting that you have made on your facebook developer account ,it may not properly configure.may be it is not active yet.

if active provide me screen-shots ,i will help you.

Comment: It is active. All configured by the book.

Comment: Can you provide me screenshot

Comment: Can u provide that screenshot??

Comment: Ok...i'll check your code and let u know if any error

Comment: It is strange as there seems like there is no error with my code. I guess something is up! Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: Had you set permission in code when click on button

Comment: Refer this doc for login.

Comment: Still doesn't answer it. Still having the problems. Keep trying different work arounds.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWERED:

I figured out a work around in the end after trying every work around and all of Facebooks iOS 9 procedures.

Instead of dragging the frameworks into the project individually I put the FacebookSDKs folder into Documents folder and then dragged that whole FacebookSDKs folder into the project (Into the Frameworks section of my project).

It then loaded but this time worked from then on so now my frameworks look a bit like this....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use *ParseFacebookUtils**V4**.framework*, the new framework for latest facebook SDK and check if you use **FacebookSDK 4+**